# Python Counter within a Counter for each item?

Tags: python

I want to create a counter for each item and the number of rankings (1-5) of the occurrences.

For example the structure is ["DATE", "PRODUCT", "RANKING"]

```
[["1/1/15", "Product 1", "4"], ["1/1/15", "Product 1", "4"],       
 ["2/2/15", "Product 1", "1"], ["1/1/15", "Product 2", "1"], 
 ["1/1/15", "Product 2", "1"], ["3/1/15", "Product 2", "1"]]
```

The wanted output would be

```
 Date: 1/1/15, Product: 1, Ranking: 4, Seen: 2
 Date: 2/2/15, Product: 1, Ranking: 1, Seen: 1 
 Date: 1/1/15, Product: 2, Ranking: 1, Seen: 2
 Date: 3/1/15, Product: 2, Ranking: 1, Seen: 1
```

I want to make a counter of each date with each product separate of the ranking.

```
    cc = Counter((rank, week) for rank, week in date_array)
```

I have tried that but that would only make a counter for the dates, however I want to take into different products.

How would I do that? Would it be nested counters?  Ultimately I want to write this information to a CSV.

Comment: If you data is as described list of tuples then you can directly call `c = Counter(data)` would do what you want...

Comment: @achampion that might be my fault. He originally made them lists and I edited them to be tuples to be more stylistically consistent. However `Counter` can't index lists, so that's probably the issue. I'm reverting.

Answer (score 3):

The same pattern as previously provided works, convert your nested lists to tuples, here's the generic form without unpacking:

```
c = Counter(tuple(i) for i in data)
for k, v in c.items():
    print("Date: {}, Product: {}, Ranking: {}, Seen: {}".format(*k, v))
```

Answer (score 1):

From your given output, it LOOKS like what you're trying to do to get a `Counter` object that counts the whole tuple. That's surprisingly easy.

```
from collections import Counter

data = [["1/1/15", "Product 1", "4"], ["1/1/15", "Product 1", "4"],       
        ["2/2/15", "Product 1", "1"], ["1/1/15", "Product 2", "1"], 
        ["1/1/15", "Product 2", "1"], ["3/1/15", "Product 2", "1"]]

cc = Counter(map(tuple, data))

for grp,seen in cc.items():
    date, product, ranking = grp
    product = product.split()[-1] # grab just the product number
                                  # consider changing this in your data model
    ordering = [date, product, ranking, seen]
    print("Date: {}, Product: {}, Ranking: {}, Seen: {}".format(*ordering))
```